# One-To-Many with dependent entity pointing to derived of principal?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

Recently I've been upgrading an EF Core 2.x application to EF Core 3.1.x
In the 2.x codebase attributes on entities were used to define relationships, whereas in the 3.1 version the EF Core fluent api must be used.
I'm having a problem with properly re-defining one of the one-to-may relationships in EF Core 3.1.

The relation in question is (simplified) as follows:

```
public abstract class User {

    public int UserId {get; set;}

    private ICollection<Pair> _pairs;

    public IEnumerable<Pair> Pairs => _pairs?.ToList();

    // More unrelated columns 
}

public class UserA : User {
    // More unrelated columns 
}

public class UserB : User {
    // More unrelated columns 
}
```

```
public class Pair
{
    public int UserAId { get; private set; }

    public int UserBId { get; private set; }

    public UserA UserA { get; private set; }

    public UserB UserB { get; private set; }

    // More unrelated columns 
}
```

That is, a User can be in many pairs, but a pair must strictly consist of one UserA and one UserB.

In 2.x this was configured like this in the datacontext:

```
    builder.Entity<UserA>().HasBaseType<User>();
    builder.Entity<UserB>().HasBaseType<User>();

    builder.Entity<Pair>()
        .HasOne(m => m.UserA)
        .WithMany(m => m.Pairs)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<Pair>()
        .HasOne(m => m.UserB)
        .WithMany(m => m.Pairs)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
     
     builder.Entity<Pair>().HasKey(m => new { m.UserAId, m.UserBId});
```

and with

```
    [ForeignKey("UserAId")]
    public UserA UserA { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserBId")]
    public UserB UserB { get; private set; }
```

In the Pair entity as well as

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId {get; set;}
```

In the User class.

I'm having some trouble properly representing this in the EF Core 3.1.x fluent api though. What I have so far is (In addition to the entity classes listed above):

```
    builder.Entity<UserA>().HasBaseType<User>();
    builder.Entity<UserB>().HasBaseType<User>();

    builder.Entity<Pair>()
        .HasKey(m => new { m.UserAId, m.UserBId });

    builder.Entity<Pair>().HasOne(p => p.UserA).WithMany(s => s.Pairs)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserAId);

    builder.Entity<Pair>().HasOne(p => p.UserB).WithMany(s => s.Pairs)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserBId);
```

(User does not need a 'key' attribute since UserId is configured as key automatically by EF Core)

Now this 'works', but it has the disadvantage that whereas in EF Core 2.x I could include the Pairs on a User like so `someUserQueryable.Include(u => u.Pairs);` whereas in 3.1.x I have to do it like

```
someUserQueryable.Include(u => (u as UserA).Pairs).Include(u => (u as UserB).Pairs);
```

Trying to do it on just User will yield `InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.`

I have also tried configuring the relation by adding this:

```
    builder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Pairs).WithOne().HasForeignKey("UserAId").HasConstraintName("FK_Pairs_Users_UserAId");
    builder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Pairs).WithOne().HasForeignKey("UserBId").HasConstraintName("FK_Pairs_Users_UserBId");
```

where the constraints are the already existing FK constraints in the database.
And while it works such that Pairs can be included on either UserA or UserB, EF Core only respect the line that is executed last, presumably because the config is on User.Pairs, and is then overwritten by the "same" configuration again, which means that only one of the User types can have Pairs associated with it. Inspecting the SQL generated with this setup yields some `(..) INNER JOIN "Pairs" ON u."UserId" = p."UserBId" WHERE p."Discriminator" = 'UserA' (...)` which will obviously never be true.

So, what am I doing wrong in this configuration? Or is this one of the (many) new shortcomings of EF Core 3.1?